# monitoring jboss process with icinga/nagios

Tags: python, shell, jboss, nagios, icinga

I want to monitor jboss if its running or not through Icinga.

I don't want to check `/etc/inid.d/jboss status` as sometimes service is up but some of the jboss is killed or hang & jboss doesn't work properly.

I would like to create a script to monitor all of its process from `ps` output. But few servers are running in standalone mode, domain(master,slave) and processes are different for each case.

I'm not sure from where do I start. Anyone here who did same earlier? Just looking for the idea to do this.

Comment: Have you tried 'check_jboss' or 'check_jboss_status' from the Nagios Exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by monitored jboss process using `ps aux | grep "\-D\[Standalone\]`" for standalone mode and `ps aux | grep "\-D\[Server"` for domain mode.

Answer (score 1):

Reading about the availability of plugins from a quick Google search led me to JMX. And obviously check_jmx4perl and Jolokia which have been a swiss army knife for monitoring java application servers. I've used it with tomcat and websphere but it should work with jboss as well.

In case you're using Icinga 2, there already is a contributed plugin check command definition available.

http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/plugin-check-commands?highlight-search=jmx#plugin-check-command-jmx4perl

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here : [check_jmx](https://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=1274&cf_id=24), this will monitor jboss process. You need to add some $JAVA_OPTS to enable this in jboss.